# Why invalid model name is not worked out in catch (Exception block?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

In laravel, Inertiajs2, vuejs3 app when sending request to server I try to catch
possible error on server and pass error to common JS function. So I do on client :

```
    formEditor.value.post(route('admin.cms_items.store'), {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onError: (e) => {
            console.log(e)
            showRTE(e)
        }
    })
```

and it works ok if I call undefined model method saRRve :

```
public function store(CMSItemRequest $request)
{

    $request= request();

    $CMSItem = null;
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $CMSItem = new CMSItem;
        $CMSItem->title = $request->title;
        ...
        $CMSItem->saRRve();
        DB::commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        return back()->withErrors(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }

}
```

But if in code above I change one line with invalid model name :

```
    $CMSItem = new CMSItemUUUU;
```

I see laravel error dialog : https://prnt.sc/DtWTJCr-sfdL

I expected that catch (Exception $e had to catch this error in the same way.

Why so  and how to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: A reason for not getting error while calling an undefined method on your class is that php `__call()` magic method is defined on that class which gets executed when you call an undefined method. Also `try` can't catch errors that are not throwing any exception.

Comment: Can be any practical decision here ? Maybe to remade it somehow?